# Bootstrap:Multiple page navigation within a modal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, bootstrap-modal

I am working on a sprint management tool.The scrum master gets to select from a list of bugs available to him.

Once he selects and hits 'Add bugs' - he needs to provide the justification individually for adding each bug.

I am planning to do this via **a single modal**  (Bootstrap 2.3.2)

**[Suppose he selects 5 bugs to add] -**

- Now a modal pops up which will have 5 pages - one page for each bug
- Each page should show the details of a bug and take in the justification.
- Then he goes to the next page(bug) within the same modal.
- After such 5 pages - he will get a submit option.

I am not sure if this is possible or if is the the best way - any better alternative UI design to glean the info would be a great help.[image]

Comment: It doesn't sound like your question is quite ready for Stack Overflow yet. For critique and discussion on the particular UX of this feature you want, you should consider asking a question on http://ux.stackexchange.com/. Once you've definitely settled on an approach, try coding it, and post a question here if you run into a programming-related problem that you are unable to solve yourself.

Comment: Thanks @Serlite for the advice.I will do accordingly.